# Difference In hexdump output on OSX and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, hex, hexdump

I am taking hex dump of the same file from two Machines ( Mac & Linux), but the order bytes looks different in both. I am something wrong?

Hexdump output from OSX

```
➜  samples hexdump 1500_77807e3eb2eeacd9ac870c24103f5b_fno.bin
0000000 02 20 00 01 01 0b 1a 02 59 5a 2a 2a 31 32 33 00
0000010 40 00 05 4a fa a4 77 00 00 1c 28 40 28 02 17 ef
0000020 6a 36 00 e0 4c 01 b8 f5 32 20 a0 00 07 01 d6 00
0000030 02 00 00 c3 1f 00 01 40 1f 18 67 8f 00 2f 26 43
0000040 2d 40 96 30 89 40 11 4b a0 ff 28 34 00 35 00 02
0000050 02 58 40 bd 25 40 ec 40 01 01 40 a6 26 20 61 34
0000060 40 2d c2 5f 16 00 03 27 00 2d 11 be 00 4b 5d 0c
0000070 c0 bd 2c 40 2d 4d a0 be 06 72 40 2f 52 00 05 7e
0000080 00 96 5d 57 a0 5c 80 2d 5c be 04 b0 5d 61 bc 03
0000090 00 00 41 1c f7 a0 80 1f 05 c5 70 7d 40 c2 ce 2a
00000a0 e9 00 0e 2c dd 00 0e 24 ef 00 0e b7 f0 83 54 61
00000b0 d7 03 bb 3c 43 57 03 c6 c7 be 99 84 60 44 36 03
00000c0 54 41 d7 03 b0 e2 a2 96 00 e1 00 2e af 5c bc 43
00000d0 b7 03 ad 6d c0 5c 41 4e 9f 6c 28 00 2e 9c c9 28
00000e0 00 2e b9 43 dc 41 1d b9 c2 c4 43 b7 03 ba 51 27
00000f0 03 e7 03 bb af a0 2e 0e a6 5d dc bc 43 17 d0 a0
0000100 40 80 1f d3 30 80 c3 54 62 cc 62 ac c0 0c 11 00
0000110 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
00005d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00005dc
```

Hexdump output of the same file from Ubuntu server SSH ed in from OSX

```
exdump 1500_77807e3eb2eeacd9ac870c24103f5b_fno.bin
0000000 2002 0100 0b01 021a 5a59 2a2a 3231 0033
0000010 0040 4a05 a4fa 0077 1c00 4028 0228 ef17
0000020 366a e000 014c f5b8 2032 00a0 0107 00d6
0000030 0002 c300 001f 4001 181f 8f67 2f00 4326
0000040 402d 3096 4089 4b11 ffa0 3428 3500 0200
0000050 5802 bd40 4025 40ec 0101 a640 2026 3461
0000060 2d40 5fc2 0016 2703 2d00 be11 4b00 0c5d
0000070 bdc0 402c 4d2d bea0 7206 2f40 0052 7e05
0000080 9600 575d 5ca0 2d80 be5c b004 615d 03bc
0000090 0000 1c41 a0f7 1f80 c505 7d70 c240 2ace
00000a0 00e9 2c0e 00dd 240e 00ef b70e 83f0 6154
00000b0 03d7 3cbb 5743 c603 bec7 8499 4460 0336
00000c0 4154 03d7 e2b0 96a2 e100 2e00 5caf 43bc
00000d0 03b7 6dad 5cc0 4e41 6c9f 0028 9c2e 28c9
00000e0 2e00 43b9 41dc b91d c4c2 b743 ba03 2751
00000f0 e703 bb03 a0af 0e2e 5da6 bcdc 1743 a0d0
0000100 8040 d31f 8030 54c3 cc62 ac62 0cc0 0011
0000110 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
```

Even the 1st word is different 0220 & 2002

Comment: Looks like the file is being read in by words (16-bit).  Configure it to use bytes (8-bit).  I think it's just an endian issue.

Comment: `hexdump -C` works on Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're having an issue with both [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and [hexdump](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55770/does-hexdump-respect-the-endianness-of-its-system) defaulting to single bytes on your OSX environment and 2-byte words on your Linux environment.

To get identical output you might need to explicitly provide a format string.

Running `hexdump -e \"%07_ax\ \"\ 16/1\ \"\ %02x\"\ \"\\n\" 1500_77807e3eb2eeacd9ac870c24103f5b_fno.bin` should give you the same result in both environments.

The format string is `"%08_ax " 16/1 " %02x" "\n"` with escaping.